# How to create a class that serializes to json that represents a calender view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create a class that serializes into JSON but it isn't a active record model.

I basically want to render a calender month in JSON that I will then render using Reactjs.

So the properties should be:

1. name of month
2. list of days of the month, but with attributes like:

```
[{"day": "Thursday", "value": 1, "date": "2019-08-1"},
 {"day": "Friday", "value": 2, "date": "2019-08-2"},...]
```

What is the best way to create a class like this that will serialize to JSON easily also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Calendar
    def initialize(month, data)
        @month = month
        @data = data
    end

    def to_json
        {'month': @month, 
         'data': @data
        }.to_json
    end
end


cal = Calendar.new('jan', [{'day': '1'}])
cal.to_json
```